# Cannot load Ubuntu on Lenovo MiiX 320

Tags: usb

Good day I have the same device as this person has in this article :
[How to install Ubuntu on miix 320](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935657/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-miix-320)

but as of yet not able to get the system to boot the Ubuntu live usb.

I followed your steps but still not working. I only get the Ubuntu logo screen with 3 red dots. Is there a way to see why it is hung? How to get to a prompt to see the screen and what is starting or not etc.

I tried to add the following to the Linux line

nomodeset i915.modeset=1 fbcon=rotate:1 ---

Comment: I think the i915.modeset=1 part is overriding the nomodeset part.... did you try with ONLY nomodeset added to boot line?

Comment: I read more of the link you posted.... the options you have set are for AFTER the install... to boot to live USB, if just nomodeset does not work, try adding this on the end instead:  "set gfxpayload=keep set gfxmode=800x1280"

Comment: Hi and thank you for posting back. I tried what you suggested and dropped the i915.modeset=1 from the command . I also added the 800x1280 info. However teh screen just goes blank . closed and opened lid blank screen still.

Comment: update. I was able to boot Xubuntu live usb. 

Thisis progress. 

now if I load Xubuntu can I load Ubuntu after the fact? 

I read it uses the same repos. but as i write this short lived joy. 

I just saw an error of "Sorry , Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced and internal error

a bunch of code 

executable path 
/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
package
systemd 237-ubuntu10
problem type 
crash

etc... 

no way to save the full file. 

But the laptop is still running.

Comment: sadly the lt crashed and kicked me out. locked the screen and rotated it. but at least it did boot.